# Unable to tune Firebase (Google) MLKit Face Detection accuracy

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I'm writing an android camera app and I'm using MLKit on-device API to do Face Detection. The nice thing about this API is that it's very simple to get up and running and there is a [sample app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/java/facedetection/FaceDetectionProcessor.java) that shows how to do that, but it feels like it's very limited in what you can do with it.

My problem is that I'm getting too many false positives (low precision) and it's not something I can control seems like. The only option I can set is the `modeType` to be either `FAST_MODE` or `ACCURATE_MODE`. But what I really need is some knobs I can tweak to get to the desired precision & recall combination.

Does anybody know if there is an API I can use to get additional control over the final result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know about the options you can use when you use face detection.

```
/** Libary Options */
val options = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
   .setModeType(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE_MODE) // used to state whether the recognition process should favour either speed or accuracy, can be set to either ACCURATE_MODE or FAST_MODE. This defaults to FAST_MODE.
   .setLandmarkType(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS) // used to declare whether the recognition process should recognise facial landmarks such as the nose, eyes, mouth etc. This defaults to NO_LANDMARKS.
   .setClassificationType(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS) //  used to declare whether the recognition process should classify facial features such as whether the face is smiling or the eyes are open. This defaults to NO_CLASSIFICATIONS.
   .setMinFaceSize(0.15f) //used to define the minimum size of a face (relative to the given image) for it to be detected. This value defaults to 0.1f.
   .setTrackingEnabled(true) // used to declare whether or not an ID should be assigned to faces, for tracking faces between images. This defaults to false.
   .build()
```

I make an example but in Spanish or if you want more information about this Library read this medium post. 
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-firebase-mlkit-on-android-face-detection-part-two-de7e307c52e0

Comment: Thanks Carlosgub, but that's exactly what I'm doing (the example I linked uses that API). It  acts as a black box when it comes to having control over detection accuracy. Like a point-and-shoot camera that super easy to operate but almost impossible to get a decent quality photos with. I'm thinking to use native Camera2 API's face detection and fuse it with the ML Kit result to get more accurate results, but would love to hear more suggestions from the community.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Google doesn't seem to expose a face quality score, so I solved the problem by calculating my own face score. I used the Landmark attributes of the Face object to create my own metric, for example:

- Face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability()
- Face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability()
- Face.getLandmarks().size() //most bogus faces will not have many landmarks
- Face.getEulerY()
- Face.getEulerZ()

I found that using these head angles, number of landmarks, etc. effectively filtered out false positive faces.

Comment: Good idea @j2abro, I actually gave up ML Kit for runtime face detection and tracking (may be will use it as a fallback option at some point). I now use native camera 2 API to detect and track faces pretty reliably with 30fps rate (something that ML Kit won't produce) Sure, I don't have all the nice landmarks now but at least it's way more reliable than ML Kit's FAST or ACCURATE modes. (still can't believe it's so limited) Anyway, thanks for the great idea!

Comment: In my recent testing, some bogus faces have all default values and hence have `0` landmarks like in your answer, but lots of other bogus faces have pretty normal-looking data, including a full set of landmarks. In fact, the `getLandmarks()` method isn't available in the current SDK, so maybe Firebase ML Vision has changed since your answer?

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but could you give me a hint on how you validated the elements to say that the face is not valid? Or at least an approximation to logic. It doesn't have to be precise @j2abro